# LinkedIn API How to get company profile page info such as About section, number of employees and Location

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api

I have here a sample API request to LinkedIn org I just want to get About section, number of employees and Location of a company for example: https://www.linkedin.com/company/oracle/
So which endpoint and parameters should I use in 2023 version?

```
 var request = require('request');
    var options = {
      'method': 'GET',
      'url': 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations?ids=List(79988552,27056405)',
      'headers': {
        'LinkedIn-Version': '{version number in the format YYYYMM}',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}'
      }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(response.body);
    });
```